# Android Studio 3 unable to build kotlin fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

Im trying to use Kotlin with Android Studio 3.0 with my existing project. 
I have created a fragment using kotlin. Im trying to use the kotlin fragment in my Java Activity. But everytime i try to run it I get

```
Error:(209, 5) error: cannot find symbol class BlankFragment
```

BlankFragment.kt

```
import android.content.Context
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup

class BlankFragment : Fragment() {

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private var mParam1: String? = null
    private var mParam2: String? = null

    private var mListener: OnFragmentInteractionListener? = null

    public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View
            = FragmentUi<Fragment>().createView(AnkoContext.create(ctx, this))

}

class FragmentUi<T>: AnkoComponent<T> {
    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<T>) = with(ui) {
        verticalLayout {
            textView {
                text = R.string.app_name

            }
        }
    }
}
```

project - build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.1'
    ext.anko_version = '0.10.1'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha5'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.0.0"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        splits {
            abi {
                enable true //enables the ABIs split mechanism
                reset() //reset the list of ABIs to be included to an empty string
                include 'x86', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'x86_64', 'arm64-v8a'
                universalApk true
            }
        }
    project.ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi': 1, 'armeabi-v7a': 2, 'arm64-v8a': 3, 'mips': 5, 'mips64': 6, 'x86': 8, 'x86_64': 9]

    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(
                            com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI), 0) * 10000000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '26'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 20
    versionName "v.32"
    testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
}
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
lintOptions {
    disable "ResourceType"
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    //    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.yarolegovich:lovely-dialog:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.github.ParkSangGwon:TedPermission:v1.0.12'
    compile 'com.github.lovetuzitong:MultiImageSelector:1.2'
    compile 'com.github.piotrek1543:CustomSpinner:0.1'
    compile 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.appyvet:materialrangebar:1.3'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.5'
    compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.+'
    compile 'com.github.ericwlange:AndroidJSCore:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk25:$anko_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk25-coroutines:$anko_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:$anko_version"
    compile files('libs/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.56.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/core-1.56.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/prov-1.56.0.0.jar')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Have you tried invalidate caches/restart or a clean and rebuild of the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally was able to get it working. For anyone who is going through a similar problem.

project build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3'
    ext.anko_version = '0.10.1'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha5'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.0.0"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

app build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        splits {
            abi {
                enable true //enables the ABIs split mechanism
                reset() //reset the list of ABIs to be included to an empty string
                include 'x86', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'x86_64', 'arm64-v8a'
                universalApk true
            }
        }
    project.ext.versionCodes = ['armeabi': 1, 'armeabi-v7a': 2, 'arm64-v8a': 3, 'mips': 5, 'mips64': 6, 'x86': 8, 'x86_64': 9]

    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(
                            com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI), 0) * 10000000 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
}
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '26'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 20
    versionName "v.32"
    testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
}
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
lintOptions {
    disable "ResourceType"
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.6'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    //    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.87.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.jkwiecien:EasyImage:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.yarolegovich:lovely-dialog:1.0.4'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.github.ParkSangGwon:TedPermission:v1.0.12'
    compile 'com.github.lovetuzitong:MultiImageSelector:1.2'
    compile 'com.github.piotrek1543:CustomSpinner:0.1'
    compile 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.appyvet:materialrangebar:1.3'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.5'
    compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.+'
    compile 'com.github.ericwlange:AndroidJSCore:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk25:$anko_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk25-coroutines:$anko_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:$anko_version"
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    compile files('libs/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.56.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/core-1.56.0.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/prov-1.56.0.0.jar')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing all Kotlin dependencies other than having the version declared (you should probably update that to `1.1.3` as well, which is the latest available as of now).

You can configure your project in two ways:

- Remove the Kotlin version you have declared, and then go to `Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin in Project`, and follow the steps presented there.
- Alternatively, you can do it in a more manual way by following the steps described [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#targeting-android) to set up the Kotlin Gradle plugin, including following the link that's there and setting up the standard library dependency as well.